# building a web app in java that take inputs from html form and post data to the api

Tags: java, html, xml

> Hi everyone i am having a problem i need to take data from html form and send it via api using java  its showing error  that method is not allowed
> Maybe you can help with  an example on how i can achieve this by getting  data from the form and pass it to java and send to the server as a post method

```java
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/priced")
public class UserData extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;
   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       request.getParameter("Channel");
       request.getParameter("Session");
       request.getParameter("Username");
       request.getParameter("Password");
       String id = request.getParameter("@ID");
       String date_of_birth = request.getParameter("DOB");
       String residency = request.getParameter("Residency");
       String departure_country = request.getParameter("DepartureCountry");
       String travel_item = request.getParameter("TravelItemValue");
       String address = request.getParameter("CoverCountry");
       String start_date = request.getParameter("StartDate");
       request.getParameter("EndDate");

       if (date_of_birth.isEmpty() || residency.isEmpty() || departure_country.isEmpty() ||
           travel_item.isEmpty() || address.isEmpty() || start_date.isEmpty() || id.isEmpty()) {
           RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("sucess.jsp");
           req.include(request, response);
       } else {
           RequestDispatcher req = request.getRequestDispatcher("Response.jsp");
           req.forward(request, response);
       }
   }
}
```

HTML CODE

```html
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Hepstar</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Travel Details</h1>
        <form action=" https://uat.gateway.insure/products/priced" method="post" enctype="application/xml" >
        <table style="with: 50%">
        <div class="XMLcomplexContent">
        <div class="Request">
        <input type="hidden" value="Request" name=".tg" />
       
    
         <div class="XMLcomplexContent">
        <div class="Authentication">
        <input type="hidden" value="Authentication" name=".tg" />
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="Channel">
        <input type="hidden" class="Channel" name="Channel" value="API" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="Session">
        <input type="hidden" class="Session" name="Session" value="{{$guid}}" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="Username">
        <input type="hidden" class="Username" name="Username" value="impdistributor" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="Password">
        <input type="hidden" class="Password" name="Password" value="FFRyEGGmMJYHA" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <input type="hidden" value="/Authentication" name=".tg" />
        </div>
        </div>
    <div class="XMLcomplexContent">
        <div class="RequestParameters">
        <input type="hidden" value="RequestParameters" name=".tg" />
        <div class="XMLcomplexContent">
        <div class="Insureds">
        <input type="hidden" value="Insureds" name=".tg" />
        <div class="XMLcomplexContent">
        <div class="Insured">
        <input type="hidden" value="Insured" name=".tg" />
        <span class="XMLattribute">
        <span class="ID">
        <label>ID: </label>
        <input type="number" class="ID" name="@ID" value="1" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="DOB">
        <label>DOB: </label>
        <input type="date" class="DOB" name="DOB" value="1983-09-25" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="Residency">
        <label>Residency: </label>
        <input type="text" class="Residency" name="Residency" value="AE" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <div class="XMLcomplexContent">
        <div class="TravelInformation">
        <input type="hidden" value="TravelInformation" name=".tg" />
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="TravelItemValue">
        <label>TravelItemValue: </label>
        <input type="number" class="TravelItemValue" name="TravelItemValue" value="1000" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <input type="hidden" value="/TravelInformation" name=".tg" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="/Insured" name=".tg" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="/Insureds" name=".tg" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="XMLcomplexContent">
        <div class="TravelInformation">
        <input type="hidden" value="TravelInformation" name=".tg" />
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="StartDate">
        <label>StartDate: </label>
        <input type="date" class="StartDate" name="StartDate" value="2021-12-01" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="EndDate">
        <label>EndDate: </label>
        <input type="date" class="EndDate" name="EndDate" value="2021-12-10" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="DepartureCountry">
        <label>DepartureCountry: </label>
        <input type="text" class="DepartureCountry" name="DepartureCountry" value="ZA" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <div class="XMLcomplexContent">
        <div class="CoverCountries">
        <input type="hidden" value="CoverCountries" name=".tg" />
        <span class="XMLsimpleType">
        <span class="CoverCountry">
        <label>CoverCountry: </label>
        <input type="text" class="CoverCountry" name="CoverCountry" value="BH" onfocus="focusGained(this)" onchange="textChanged(this)" /></span>
        <br/></span>
        <input type="hidden" value="/CoverCountries" name=".tg" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="/TravelInformation" name=".tg" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="/RequestParameters" name=".tg" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="/Request" name=".tg" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </table>
        
        <p><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
        </form></div>
        </body>
        </html>`
```

Comment: Hi Leo, can you share the error message?

Comment: This error (HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed) means that this program was able to connect to the website, but the site has a programming error. This shows the formart of the xml is in correct.the url only accept post method

Comment: dont you think there should be `@Override` on the doPost method ?

Comment: i did try to put @overide shows error the form data seems okay but the java to xml thats where the case is

Comment: the xml looks like this                                                                                           <Request>
<Authentication>
  <Channel>API</Channel>
  <Session>{{$guid}}</Session>
  <Username>impdistributor</Username>
  <Password>FFRyEGGmMJYHA</Password>
 </Authentication>
    </Request>